# How many candies will I recieve when trading Pokémon that do not contain a capture location?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you trade Pokémon with other trainers, the amount of candy you receive is based on the distance between the two Pokémon.

[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001518407-Trading-Pok%C3%A9mon)

> The amount of Candy you earn depends on the distance between where the two Pokémon were caught. The further the distance, the more Candy.

Pokémon captured by field research prior to the trading system do not contain a capture location. After the trading system was released, Pokémon captured by field research now contain the capture location

[image: Articuno without capture location]
[image: Articuno with capture location]

Given how the number of candies is based on distance between where the Pokémon were caught, how many candies would I receive when trading Pokémon that do not contain a capture location?

What if both Pokémon do not contain a capture location and there is no distance to calculate?

Comment: Note that you receive candy for the Pokemon you trade away, not the one your receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one, unfortunately, as there is no geo-location data to base on your trade. This does not double during double candy trade events.

Most (not all) Pokémon without geo-location data come from early Research Task rewards, where a geo-location was not attached to your Pokémon's catch location.

Use this to strategically decide which Pokémon to trade with a fellow trainer, if you are going for increased distance for Badges or candy for leveling up.

Comment: Per your edit, can you provide a reason why I would want to transfer location-less Pokemon to Let's Go? I do not see how that is relevant to my question

Comment: @Wondercricket: I'm assuming it's instead of trading it to a different *Go* player. You could also just keep it, of course. But if you're going to trade it, it might be more efficient to trade it to a *Let's Go* account instead since there's no geo-based distance mechanic.

Comment: @Ellesdil you is correct, but this would be better served as a comment as it does not add to your question but is rather an option/opinion.